# Android FindFragmentByTag returns null in FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to retrieve a fragment from my fragmentTabHost:

```
private void initView() {
    FragmentTabHost mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("summary").setIndicator("Summary"),
            SummaryActivity.class, bundle);

    SummaryActivity summaryActivity = (SummaryActivity) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("summary");
    System.out.println(summaryActivity);
}
```

When I try to get my fragment immediately after it was created, **it returns null**. It could be a thread issue. How, or even when, should I call getFragmentByTag to retrieve my fragment in this case?

Answer (score 2):

The `Fragment` you are looking for is not in the stack. It is not even added/present at the time you are finding it back.

`findFragmentByTag` method will look and match last fragment that added in the transaction, if that is not matching with the required one, then it will search with the available list from history. Finally if your tag is not there with any fragments it will `return null`.

Make sure that , you are adding the `Fragment` to the view first.

the view should receive the fragment/tabhost to make it available in the lifecycle.

you have to return your `tabHost` to the view to add the fragment before you do `findFragmentByTag` lookup.

For ex:

You are in your `Fragment`'s `onCreateView` then you should do return the `tabhost` to the view after you inflated it.

```
onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment1);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmenttag").setIndicator("Fragmenttag"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);

        return mTabHost;
}
```

Then probably your `Fragment` will be available in back stack , you can get it back by `Tag`.

Comment: I'm using a FragmentActivity for my parent view (where my tabhost is created). There isn't an onCreateView, so i'm calling initView() in onCreate. This doesn't allow me to return a view, since onCreate returns a void. Note: if I add onCreateView, it says that it is unreachable

Comment: Using FragmentActivity have some limitations on the fragment transaction. So what is your requirement for finding the tag again, like why do you need to do so.

Comment: Fragment which is assigned to tabhost but not yet selected will not be there in stack. Try it by make the fragment selected and try to get it by findfragmmentById

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically change things in the child tab from the parent view. I think it is selected by default (however i may be wrong. if so, how would you do this?). Also, newTabSpec sets a tag but not a id. How would I findfragmentbyid?

Comment: FragmentActivity Limitaion : When using the <fragment> tag, this implementation can not use the parent view's ID as the new fragment's ID. You must explicitly specify an ID (or tag) in the <fragment>.

Answer (score 0):

Fragment Tags can only be set during fragment transactions. The tab host tag refers to something else. Try using findFragmentById() if you set an id on the fragments root view.